# python decorator losing argument definitions

Tags: python, decorator, xml-rpc, functools

I am using a block like this:

```
def served(fn) :    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        p = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(SERVER, allow_none=True )
        return (p.__getattr__(fn.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)) # do the function call
    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper,fn)

@served
def remote_function(a, b):
    pass
```

to wrap a series of XML-RPC calls into a python module.  The "served" decorator gets called on stub functions to expose operations on a remote server.

I'm creating stubs like this with the intention of being able to inspect them later for information about the function, specifically its arguments.

As listed, the code above does not transfer argument information from the original function to the wrapper.  If I inspect with `inspect.getargspec( remote_function )` then I get essentially an empty list, instead of `args=['a','b']` that I was expecting.

I'm guessing I need to give additional direction to the `functools.update_wrapper()` call via the optional `assigned` parameter, but I'm not sure exactly what to add to that tuple to get the effect I want.

The name and the docstring are correctly transferred to the new function object, but can someone advise me on how to transfer argument definitions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729378/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-argspec-of-a-function-in-a-python-decorato) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995815/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-return-value-of-a-function-without-defining-new-fun) suggest that the [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator/) can do this.

Comment: Yes, I failed to find these in my searches.  Pity that there's no way to do this with the standard modules (esp functools).